# Есть ли аналог Visual Studio в Linux-based системах ?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linux

Есть ли аналог данной среды разработки в линуксе? 
Из фич мне нужны: отладка и удобный form desiner.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- [**KDevelop,**](http://kdevelop.org/) [**Qt Creator,**](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) [**Eclipse**](http://www.eclipse.org/)
- Олдскульные пацаны дебажатся с помощью [**gdb**](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/) в консоли
- Постановка вопроса про `form designer` не очень корректна, так как понятно, что `MFC` и прочих вещей для разработки `GUI` под `Linux` нет, а `Visual Studio` привязана именно к ним

Comment: Ну у gdb и фронтендов немало. На разный вкус.

Comment: @alexlz Ну, собственно, первые 3 из этого списка вполне себе как неплохо работают с `gdb` :)

Comment: Не-не-не, дух старой школы живет в Emacs/vim, которые отлично работают фронтэндами (M-x gdb). Работать с голой консолью gdb - это когда вопрос пяти минут, а так это, вроде бы, не особо труЪ.

Comment: Ну [X]Emacs + gdb -- это классика, vim + gdb -- кто его знает, возможно экзотика. А "голая консоль gdb" (как эротично!) -- тоже инструмент. И, благодаря мощности gdb, весьма нехилый. Отладчик, дока по которому имеет объём полтысячи страниц, умеет много (в т.ч. и свои скрипты. А с некоторых пор -- ещё и на питоне)

Comment: Ну, есть еще куча других, правда, не знаю как там с GUI Layout Editor - Code::Blocks, QDevelop, Ultimate++... 

Хотелось отметить wxDev-C++, но он только под Windows

Answer (score 4):

Полного аналога нет.

Для создания интерфейсов в GTK+ можно использовать такую забавную штучку как glade

Есть аналог дельфам, Lazarus называется. Тоже предоставляет визуальное программирование.

Comment: Плюсик за Лазаря. Кстати, кайликс совсем уже стух, получается?

Comment: Kylix уже 10 лет как стух

Comment: Ну, это печально. Хотя казалось бы - вполне нормальная идея была.

Comment: Давно уже проект закрыли. Уже лет 10 назад.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вообще сотни их. И если уж на то пошло, то под линуксом можно запустить Visual Studio через wine. 6-я версия, хоть и древняя, но вполне годится для разработки и современных приложений, благо компилятор и IDE являются независимыми компонентами. Если нужно посвежее, то даже 2010 студию заставляли работать, [пруф](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892)

Еще хочу сказать, что существует такая классная штука как VisualAssist от фирмы WholeTomato. Это надстройка к VS, которая очень существенно облегчает жизнь разработчику. На winehq пишут, что под вайном эта надстройка нормально не работает, но стоит попробовать...

Answer (score 0):

qt creator

Comment: @alex_55555, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 0):

Юзай vim и g++ через консоль(ну и gdb, по надобности)

Comment: g++ через консольку неудобно - лучше черкз makefile или систему сборки